# Spring Security and AngularJs WITHOUT Spring Boot

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Every tutorial I see with Spring MVC and AngularJs uses Spring Boot configuration. I am not using Spring Boot so I'm wondering if there are any pointers anybody has on how to handle AngularJS login submission server side WITHOUT using Spring Boot.

So my form is the same basic one from the Spring Security demo [here](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii)

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="error">
  There was a problem logging in. Please try again.
</div>
<form role="form" ng-submit="login()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username:</label> <input type="text"
            class="form-control" id="username" name="username" ng-model="credentials.username"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password:</label> <input type="password"
            class="form-control" id="password" name="password" ng-model="credentials.password"/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The function to authenticate on login() is as follows:

```
//the authentication function
var authenticate = function(credentials, callback){
  var headers = 
          credentials ? 
          {
            authorization : "Basic " + btoa(credentials.username + ":" + credentials.password)
          } 
          : {};
  $http.get('user', {headers : headers}).success(function(data){
    if(data.userName){
      $rootScope.authenticated = true;
    } else {
      $rootScope.authenticated = false;
    }
    callback && callback();
  }).error(function(){
    $rootScope.authenticated = false;
    callback && callback();
  });
};
```

So now the next part is to configure Spring to handle the username and password properties of the credentials object. On the server side, I have a basic WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  DataSource dataSource;

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

     http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/profile").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()  
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/signin")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
            //.and()
            //.requiresChannel()
            //  .antMatchers("/register").requiresSecure();
    }


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws    Exception {
        auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()

    }

 }
```

I know I have to configure a java.security.Principal in there somehow, but like I said, anything I've found has been for spring boot.